# R: generate random number using column value with data table

Tags: r, random, data.table

I have a very large dataset and would like to generate a column with random integers with the maximum value of the range taken from another column. In base R, it would be:

```
dt$random <- sample(1:dt$value, size=nrow(dt), rep = TRUE)
```

How can I do this using data table since I would like this to run quicker? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to draw a random number between `1` and `dt$value`, where `dt$value` is different in every row? Because that is not what your `sample()` call does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the performance difference between `data.table` and base R for this will be very small. In base R, I would do it like this:

```
dt$random = ceiling(runif(n = nrow(dt), min = 0, max = df$value))
```

A data.table equivalent is

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
dt[, random := ceiling(runif(n = .N, min = 0, max = df$value))]
```

In both cases it will take much more time to draw the random numbers than to add them to the data structure, but `data.table` will be more efficient at adding the random numbers to the data structure, once generated. So that tiny part of this operation will be more optimized.

Comment: Since integers (and possibly non-repeating integers if this set is being used to partition the dataset) are being sought, then `sample` done on 1:nrow(dt) might be better.

Comment: Definitely - if that's what OP wants. But reading their text *"with the maximum value of the range taken from another column"* and seeing their code `sample(1:dt$value` (sic), I think OP does not want integers that partition the dataset. I think they want an independent `1:N_max` draw for each row where the `N_max` value varies by row and is found in the `dt$value` column. That's why I'm using a rounded `runif`: unlike `sample` the `max` arg of `runif` is vectorized.

Comment: @GregorThomas thank you! You are right that the code is not the "correct" one for base R but i wasn't sure how to express it best.